# Layout Legend changes when the created project in QGIS 3.16 opened in QGIS 3.22

Tags: qgis, symbology, legend, layouts, version-control

I created a project in QGIS 3.16. This project has 10 layers with different symbology. In the layout I chose one of this layers symbology for Legend.
Now I have upgradeed my QGIS to 3.22. When I want to open this project in QGIS 3.22, It shows all layers symblogy in legend. The legend in QGIS 3.16 is not same as QGIS 3.22. It automatically activates all layers symbols in legend.

[image: Legend in QGIS 3.16]

[image: Legend in QGIS 3.22.10]

Because I have many projects I can not edit all of them manually.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide images to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Okay @Erik. As you see when I open the project created in 3.16 in 3.22, Legend structure is completely change to default.